# Storybook Addon Specifications test status doesn't get update

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, add-on, storybook

I am using Storybook addon `storybook-addon-specifications` to write my unit tests. I am encountering a problem on situations where I have to use `setTimeout` function.

In such scenarios user interaction and console logs acts on desired outputs while the Log of Test status in Specifications tag remain outdated. Sample code is as follow:

```
it('Get Cookie', () => {
    setTimeout(() => {
        expect(mobstore.loginState.loggedIn).toEqual(true);
    }, 3100);
 })
```

Comment: From what I saw by testing it, it seems that the functionality to return promises (in order to use it for the setTimeout) doesn't exist to the functions `describe` and `expect`

Comment: I am unable to add the addon successfully as it giving me errors . Did one of you successfully add it ?